# how to validate select tag with request file

Tags: laravel

i have a list tag in laravel and error message tag:

```
 {!! Form::select('Order[]', ['NULL' => '', 'o1' => 'order1', 'o2' => 'order2','o3'=>'order3'], null,['class'=>'myform-select']) !!}
   @error('Order')
           <h6 class="text-danger text-center err-message">{{$message}}</h6>
   @enderror
```

and in request php file defined validating is:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
             "Order"=>"array|required"
        ];
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return[
            "Order.required"=>"you must select one order",
            "Order.array"=>"you must select one order"
        ];
    }
```

and in controller :

```
public function store(taskrequest $request)
    {
        //
    }
```

However, if you do not select any order, the error message will not be displayed,This works for other tags like input

Comment: fyi, your `<h6>` ends with `<h3>`. I _think_ you need an additional `Order.*` validation

Comment: how to use Order.* validation?

Comment: I have no idea, maybe https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-in can help

Comment: I also think this has nothing to do with your element being a `<select>` but having multiple selects with the same name `Order[]` - your validation probably also wouldn't work with multiple `<input>`s

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can check and modify

**Check Blade File:**
Make sure that the Blade file where you display the form is within a form tag with the correct method (POST) and action (the URL that routes to your store method in the controller).

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'your.route.name', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
{!! Form::select('Order[]', ['NULL' => '', 'o1' => 'order1', 'o2' => 'order2', 'o3' => 'order3'], null, ['class' => 'myform-select']) !!}
@error('Order')
    <h6 class="text-danger text-center err-message">{{$message}}</h6>
@enderror
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Check Validation Rules:**
In your form request validation rules, you are requiring the "Order" field to be an array. If you're using a multiple-select dropdown, this is correct. However, if it's a single-select dropdown, you should remove the array validation.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        "Order" => "required", // Remove the "array" validation
    ];
}
```

**Check Validation Messages:**
In your messages function, you're providing custom messages for the "required" and "array" rules. Make sure that the messages are correctly spelled and match the validation rules.

**Check the Controller:**
Ensure that you are calling the validate method in your controller. This is usually done automatically if you type-hint your form request in the controller method.

```
public function store(TaskRequest $request)
{
    // The validation automatically happens before reaching here
    // If the validation fails, it will redirect back with error messages
    // Otherwise, your store logic goes here
}
```

By checking these points, you should be able to identify and fix the issue with the error message not displaying when no order is selected.